# PHP loop with set intervals

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have the following code that converts my twitter account rss feed into a string so that I can parse my followers user names.

```
$url = file_get_contents("MY_TWITTER_RSS_FEED_URL_GOES_HERE");
$source = simplexml_load_string($url);

foreach ($source as $match){

    //name of node
    $username = "&nbsp@".$match->author->name;
    //removes the name and parentheses ex.kyrober555 (Robert)
    $usernames = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, ' '));
    //returns usernames only ex.kyrober555
    echo $usernames;
    }
```

Using the foreach loop I return all 15 names from the feed and it looks like this.

```
 @ajay54 @marymary770 @funnigurl1209 @jimiwhitten @kyroberthl @tree_bear @crftyldy @sanbrt63 @Sandra516 @DreamFog @KravenSwagNBzz @DreamFog @TheCrippledDuck @TheCrippledDuck @Cass60
```

Now here is what I would like to do, but I am not sure if its possible, and I wouldn'y know how so I ask for your help. When I load the page for this php file it returns all user names at once. What I would like to do is return 5 user names then do something then return 5 more then do something else then return the last 5. Maybe something like this but I don't know...

```
foreach ($source as $match){
    /* Return the 1st 5 user names */

        /* do some other type of coding */

    /* Return the second set of 5 usernames */

        /* do something here */

    /* return the last 5 usernames */
    }
```

Ultimately returning all 15 user names, but at different intervals not all at once.

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX :-)

Comment: Twitter has an API that can tell you your followers' user names...

Comment: But WHY? If it is just firework for the user's eyes get them in an array, then use JS to animate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($source as $match){
    $username = "&nbsp@".$match->author->name;
    $usernames = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, ' '));
    echo $usernames;
    if($count % 5 == 0 && $count > 0) {
        // do something else;
    } 
    $count++;
}
```

Thanks @vichle for you comment, maybe it's better to use a matrix then?

```
$count = 0;
$userArray = array();    
foreach ($source as $match){
    $username = "&nbsp@".$match->author->name;
    $usernames = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, ' '));
    $userArray[$count % 5][] = $usernames;
    $count++;
}
```

This code will probably need tweaking, but it's a start.. Now you've got an array within an array. $userArray[0] will return an array with the first 5 usernames, $userArray[1] will return an array with the second 5 usernames, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't this just do something different to every fifth element, instead of doing something with the first five, something else with the 6th to 10th element and again something else with the 11th to 15th element.

Comment: i tried $userArray[0] but it just shows ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray over n over again but no user names. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is always nice. Something like this maybe:

```
for($offset = 0; $offset < count($array); $offset += 5){
    $slice = array_slice($array, $offset, 5);
    // Do your stuff
}
```